# How to convert a JavaScript object to a PHP array and get the raw string?

Tags: javascript, php

In my application I need to convert a JavaScript Object to a raw PHP array returned as text string. I would do this calling an API. I don't need to manupulate the array. In my JavaScript application, I just need the plain PHP object string as showed below. (Like using this: https://wtools.io/convert-js-object-to-php-array)

**The JavaScript object is:**

```
{
"name":"A Name",
"_typography": {
  "color": {
    "hex":"#2196f3"
  },
  "text-transform":"uppercase",
  "font-weight":"600"
  }
}
```

**How I send the JavaScript Object to the PHP function**

```
JSON.stringify(jsObject);
```

**What I need as string output:**

```
[
"name" => "A Name",
"_typography" => [
  "color" => [
    "hex" => "#2196f3"
  ],
  "text-transform" => "uppercase",
  "font-weight" =>"600"
  ]
]
```

What I tried is to first `json_decode` the JavaScript object to a PHP object and then try to return it as a plain string back. But no chance. Either I get a Js Object back or something else entirely. I have no more ideas.

**My try**

```
function convert_js_object_to_php(WP_REST_Request $request) {

    // Getting the JS object
    $object = $request->get_header('js_object');

    // Decoding it to a PHP object
    $output = json_decode($object);

    if ($output) {
        return strval($output);
        // return $output (Here I also get the JavaScript object again)
        // return implode($output) (I don't get the plain PHP array)
    }

    return false;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You're using [json_decode()](https://php.net/json_decode) so I presume it's actually JSON and not a random JavaScript object like `{createdAt: new Date()}`. No idea what "no chance" means, but you're using [strval()](https://php.net/strval) to destroy the object and seemingly convert it back to string.

Comment: It's a JavaScript object which I pass with `JSON.stringify()`. Using `strval()` on the json_decoded object gives me just a 500 error.. :-)

Comment: Are you sure? You want to get a string representation of a PHP array to be returned from the PHP to the Javascript? What use is that to the javascript?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's for a code generator purpose which runs in Angular, but generates Code for a PHP application. The user gets a big JavaScript object, but need to rewrite it in PHP. Or he can use such a tool: https://wtools.io/convert-js-object-to-php-array but a in app solution would be better.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

`$incoming` is the jsonString coming from the javascript code

```
$incoming = '{
    "name":"A Name",
    "_typography": {
      "color": {
        "hex":"#2196f3"
      },
      "text-transform":"uppercase",
      "font-weight":"600"
      }
    }';

$a = json_decode($incoming, true);
echo var_export($a);
```

RESULT

```
array (
  'name' => 'A Name',
  '_typography' => 
  array (
    'color' => 
    array (
      'hex' => '#2196f3',
    ),
    'text-transform' => 'uppercase',
    'font-weight' => '600',
  ),
)
```

Comment: YES! You're the man!!  Just as additional question: Is it also possible to use the short array syntax here with square brackets?

Comment: I dont know of a way

Answer (score 1):

Only changes are that you should add true to json_decode and use var_export to get the php array string. If you wanted to get square bracket you could write some custom string generator code.

```
function convert_js_object_to_php() {

    // Getting the JS object
    $object = $request->get_header('js_object');

    // Decoding it to a PHP object
    $output = json_decode($object, true);
    if ($output) {
        return var_export($output, true);
    }

    return false;
}
```